# proving that $\left | \det A \right |\geq 2^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be an invertible matrix.

Need to prove that if each entry of $A$ is $-1$ or $1$ so $\left | \det A \right |\geq 2^{n-1}$

So it reminds me of Hadamard's maximum determinant problem, but I still can't see how to prove it.

Comment: the determinant is an integer divisible by $2^{n-1}$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem#Connection_of_the_maximal_determinant_problems_for_.7B1.2C.C2.A0.E2.88.921.7D_and_.7B0.2C.C2.A01.7D_matrices

Comment: @user8268 you ought to make that an answer; I don't think we'll do better than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to deal with this is to use Smith Normal Form. Since we know that $A$ is invertible, the theory of the Smith Normal Form tells that there are integral matrices $U$ and $V$, each of determinant $\pm 1$ such that $UAV = {\rm diag}(d_{1},d_{2},\ldots,d_{n}),$ where $d_{i} |d_{i+1}$ for each $i.$ Since the rank of $A$ (mod $2$) is $1$, and the same applies to $UAV,$ we conclude that $d_{1}$ is odd, and that $d_{i}$ is even for $i > 1.$
Hence ${\rm det}(A) = \pm {\rm det}(UAV)$ is divisible by $2^{n-1}.$ The approach to this particular question in the Wikipedia article is perhaps more direct, but the theory of the Smith Normal Form is powerful in many contexts.

Comment: very nice; I prefer it to the solution I found on Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

As the above comment points out, the question is answered quite thoroughly in [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem#Connection_of_the_maximal_determinant_problems_for_.7B1.2C.C2.A0.E2.88.921.7D_and_.7B0.2C.C2.A01.7D_matrices), which proves that the determinant is always divisible by $2^{n-1}$ (which implies the desired conclusion).